# How can I copy an image file in node/electron and be able to paste it as a file to another directory in windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, cmd, electron

I have built an image viewing app using electron js for windows 10. I am able to add viewed images to the clipboard using clipboard.writeImage. However, using this, I can only paste into word and other editing applications. I would like to be able to paste my image as a file as well so then it can be copied into folders. Is there a way to do this in nodejs? I also do not mind if the command is given in powershell or cmd as i can call either one from nodejs.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the images to (temporary) files, you can copy references to these files to the clipboard with 
[`Set-Clipboard -LiteralPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell it could look something like this:

```
$Image = Get-Clipboard -Format Image
$ImageFile = 'C:\scripts\test\image.jpg'
$Image.Save($ImageFile,'Jpeg')
```

More info on what you can do with $Image after you've captured it here: [Image Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) and the supported formats can be found here: [ImageFormat Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error message while trying this out:                You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $Image.Save($ImageFile,'Jpeg');
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Are you sure you had an image in your clipboard? That error is what you get when $Image is empty. Add a line between the second and third with just `$Image` and you should see information about the image, if there's no output the first line failed. Which only happened to me when there was no image in the clipboard.

Comment: I _think_ the intent is for @daibatzu's application to copy images as _file references_ to the clipboard, so that users can later paste these files into folders. Daibatzu, can you clarify (please update your question directly)?

Comment: yes, mklement0, this is what I want. It is an image viewing desktop application. Users should be able to click copy on an image and paste it whenever they want into a file explorer window. Thanks

Comment: @daibatzu Ah, then you should be set with mklement0's answer, and if you need to go from "image-in-clipboard" to "file-in-clipboard" you can just combine our answers (may need some minor modifications).

Comment: This is what I tried:  Set-Clipboard -Path "C:\Users\igweo\Desktop\Pictures\77701_front.jpg"
$Image = Get-Clipboard -Format Image;
$ImageFile = 'C:\Users\igweo\Desktop\Pictures\77701_front.jpg';
$Image.Save($ImageFile,'jpg');  But I still get the same error

Comment: Ok, mkelement0 is correct, Set-Clipboard -LiteralPath "C:\Users\igweo\Desktop\Pictures\77701_front.jpg" is the correct way to do it